# How can i pass data between two widgets (files)?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am building an flutter app and I need to pass function to other widget.
[image: Screenshot of my app for better understading]

I have these 8 TextFormFields with values in it.
When I press the grey button "Smazat hodnoty pasažérů" it should clear all the text fields.

I have the textfields in one file *pasazeri.dart* and the button in another file *deleteBtn.dart*.
I think I can just send the function to clear the boxes to my button widget but it doesn't work.

This is my full code of *pasazeri.dart*

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'deleteBtn.dart';

class Pasazeri extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PasazeriState createState() => _PasazeriState();
}

class _PasazeriState extends State<Pasazeri> {
  final FocusNode pasazer1 = FocusNode();
  final FocusNode pasazer2 = FocusNode();
  final FocusNode pasazer3 = FocusNode();
  final FocusNode pasazer4 = FocusNode();
  final FocusNode pasazer5 = FocusNode();
  final FocusNode pasazer6 = FocusNode();
  final FocusNode pasazer7 = FocusNode();
  final FocusNode pasazer8 = FocusNode();

  TextEditingController contPasazer1 = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController contPasazer2 = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController contPasazer3 = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController contPasazer4 = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController contPasazer5 = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController contPasazer6 = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController contPasazer7 = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController contPasazer8 = TextEditingController();

  _fieldFocusChange(
      BuildContext context, FocusNode currentFocus, FocusNode nextFocus) {
    currentFocus.unfocus();
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(nextFocus);
  }

  void clearBoxes() {
    setState(() {
      contPasazer1.clear();
      contPasazer2.clear();
      contPasazer3.clear();
      contPasazer4.clear();
      contPasazer5.clear();
      contPasazer6.clear();
      contPasazer7.clear();
      contPasazer8.clear();
    });
  }

  Widget pasazer(cisloPasazer, controller, focusnode, next) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            "$cisloPasazer. pasažér: ",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.5, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 3),
            width: 40,
            height: 25,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color(0xFFFFDD80),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
            child: Center(
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: controller,
                focusNode: focusnode,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                onChanged: (String str) => DeleteBtn(delete: clearBoxes),
                onFieldSubmitted: (term) {
                  _fieldFocusChange(context, focusnode, next);
                },
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 15,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                cursorWidth: 1,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 9),
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  hintText: "",
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xFF9c9a98),
                  ),
                ),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                  WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
                  LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(3),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Text(" kg",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.5, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
          top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.015,
          bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.015,
          left: 8,
          right: 8),
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          vertical: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.012),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Color(0xFFa38b5f),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 6, horizontal: 10),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                pasazer(1, contPasazer1, pasazer1, pasazer2),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8),
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      pasazer(5, contPasazer5, pasazer5, pasazer6),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 6, horizontal: 10),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                pasazer(2, contPasazer2, pasazer2, pasazer3),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8),
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      pasazer(6, contPasazer6, pasazer6, pasazer7),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 6, horizontal: 10),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                pasazer(3, contPasazer3, pasazer3, pasazer4),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8),
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      pasazer(7, contPasazer7, pasazer7, pasazer8),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 6, horizontal: 10),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                pasazer(4, contPasazer4, pasazer4, pasazer5),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8),
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
                        child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              "8. pasažér: ",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 14.5, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 3),
                              width: 40,
                              height: 25,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Color(0xFFFFDD80),
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                              child: Center(
                                child: TextFormField(
                                  controller: contPasazer8,
                                  focusNode: pasazer8,
                                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                                  onFieldSubmitted: (term) {
                                    pasazer8.unfocus();
                                  },
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      fontSize: 15,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                                  cursorWidth: 1,
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    contentPadding:
                                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 9),
                                    border: InputBorder.none,
                                    hintText: "",
                                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                      color: Color(0xFF9c9a98),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                                    WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
                                    LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(3),
                                  ],
                                  onChanged: (String str) {},
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Text(" kg",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 14.5,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500))
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And here is my code of *deleteBtn.dart*

```
class DeleteBtn extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function delete;
  DeleteBtn({this.delete});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Container(
        height: 40,
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Color(0xFF616161),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
        ),
        child: FlatButton(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0),
          child: Text(
            "Smazat hodnoty pasažérů",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            print(delete);
            delete();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When i press the button i need to call the function `clearBoxes()` which is in the *pasazeri.dart*
I added `print(delete);`  to `onPressed:` and it gives me:

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
The method 'call' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: call()
```

So i think it's problem with passing the function.

Does anyone know how can i fix it?

Comment: So you try to apply the delete function in the onChange handler. What you miss is that you create a new instance everytime. Either make your btn a singleton or makd the delete function static, i guess. Or grab it .of(context)?

Comment: Isn't here any different solution? i just need to remove text from controllers when i press the button...

Comment: Hmm using a static delete would look like `=>DeleteBtn.delete=clearBoxes`

Comment: Hey @MatějMichálek, check out my answer. Hope it'll help you in a great extent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were certain problem in your code which were not letting you achieve this thing. I will point it down for you:

- No need of doing `setState()` in your `clearBoxes()`, since, it will do it's job. `setState` is used, *when there is a change in the `value` of the `state` of a variable, to be reflected in a widget.* For example: Adding `+1` on the hit of a button for `Counter` or more specifically, providing new text to your controller, `setState(() => contPasazer1.text = "New value")`
- To pass the `function` to your widget, you should be doing `delete: () => your_function_name`, **not** `delete: clearBoxes`. Your delete is a type `void`, and it is a `dart formatting error`. hence nothing works, even you pass the correct method

Let us look at the corrected code for the above instance:

```
void clearBoxed(){
  // no need of setState
  contPasazer1.clear();
  contPasazer2.clear();
  contPasazer3.clear();
  contPasazer4.clear();
  contPasazer5.clear();
  contPasazer6.clear();
  contPasazer7.clear();
  contPasazer8.clear();
}
```

Passing the `clearBoxes()` correctly to your `DeleteBtn` class argument `delete`. Do give a read on [Pass function into a function in Dart](https://alvinalexander.com/flutter/dart-how-pass-function-into-function-method-parameter/)

```
// you can also do this (){ clearBoxes() }, but below is more dart way or JS way
onChanged: (String str) => DeleteBtn(delete: () => clearBoxes())
```

Also, I wonder, why do you use `DeleteBtn()` in your `onChanged()`? If you want to use it as a button, just place there simply, and use the button

> `onChanged()` will be called every time you start writing in your specified `TextFormField`. This is not a best practise, I would suggest

For cleaner approach, you can just call the method `clearBoxes()`, when you start typing something like this:

```
onChanged: (String str) => clearBoxes()
```

And wherever you wanna use your button, you can use it by placing the `DeleteBtn` and that is it like below:

```
Row(
 children: [
    TextFormField(
       onChanged: (String str) => clearBoxes() 
    ),
    DeleteBtn(delete: () => clearBoxes())
 ]
)
```

Consider using the best practices, it will help you in the long run.

I am showing my code to show how things are working. **I have just used 3 TexFields and a DeleteBtn to show that how this works**.

*Focus on how things are working in the code, specifically, `clearBoxes()` and `DeleteBtn(delete: () => clearBoxes())`*

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  TextEditingController contPasazer1 = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController contPasazer2 = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController contPasazer3 = TextEditingController();
  
  // no need of setState()
  void clearBoxes() {
    contPasazer1.clear();
    contPasazer2.clear();
    contPasazer3.clear();
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        width: double.infinity,
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            TextFormField(controller: contPasazer1),
            SizedBox(height: 20.0),
            TextFormField(controller: contPasazer2),
            SizedBox(height: 20.0),
            TextFormField(controller: contPasazer3),
            SizedBox(height: 20.0),
            // Your delete button from another class
            DeleteBtn(delete: () => clearBoxes())
          ]
        )
      )
    );
  }
}

// Your other class
class DeleteBtn extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function delete;
  DeleteBtn({this.delete});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Container(
        height: 40,
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Color(0xFF616161),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
        ),
        child: FlatButton(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0),
          child: Text(
            "Smazat hodnoty pasažérů",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            print(delete);
            delete();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Result**

**Disclaimer:** Don't look at the UI, I would request you to look at the functionality. I have used your `DeleteBtn` only, but did not come fine with the layout, so apologies.

[image: Result]

Comment: Glad to know @MatějMichálek. Happy learning :) All the very best. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Add this line to your code:

```
import 'pasazeri.dart' as paz(..in ur deletebtn.dart)
```

Then, add this line in the `onPressed()`:

```
paz.PasazeriState().clearBoxes();
```

OR,

1. In your pasazeri.dart, add this line..above "override"

```
Pasazeri(this.clearbox);

  final bool clearbox;
```

2. Change your clearBoxes function to this-

```
void clearbox(){

bool k= widget.clearbox;//..put it in set state.

If(k){
//Delete boxes
}Else{
//Do smthng
}

}//Clearbox closes
```

3. Now, in your deletebtn.dart, inside the onPressed (), write this

```
Pasazeri(true);
```

Lemme know if this worked, i think it should.

Comment: thank you for your response but it did not work. It gives me this error: `setState() called in constructor: PasazeriState#fd32c(lifecycle state: created, no widget, not mounted)`. I also had to rename  _PasazeriState to PasazeriState...

Comment: Hi, sorry it didn't work out as expected, actually I don't have my pc right now..so..try this..in your onPressed()..write ths..Pasazeri.clearBoxes().. lemme know if ths works

Comment: I had to use PasazeriState.clearBoxes() instead of Pasazeri.clearBoxes() but even this didn't work. I also tried to to convert deleteBtn to Stateful Widget but got the same result.

Comment: I just tried to replace the function with some simple function that just print some text `print("something");` and it worked, so it has to be some problem with my function. Your suggestion works but my function doesn't.